# API backends app revision Y not the same as expected X

Tags: backend, bad-request

I have API endpoints on app engine, and after a certain deployment I found a server error. By mistake, I did a rollback, then I fixed the problem, and then I deployed again. Since then I'm having this error with this API call

```
/_ah/spi/BackendService.getApiConfigs
```

I tried to roll back a lot, tried to redeploy a lot of times, and this error is always there

```
com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod: exception occurred while calling backend method (SystemService.java:398)
com.google.api.server.spi.response.BadRequestException: API backend's app revision '405576002256244058' not the same as expected '405575422101043541'
```

Answer (score 0):

What i did to solve this, was to rebuild on my local machine, and redeploy it remotely.

I think rebuilding it locally increases the version number, so redeploying it will create a new version, and remove the problem